# Load heavy UI in onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to load very heavy UI in AsyncTask `OnPostExecute()` method that approximately takes 5 seconds to show up.

Also, I make a `Runnable` thread and post my UI through `runOnUiThread()` but still takes 5 seconds to show up, Any idea about how to optimize my code?

Comment: Never use `runOnUiThread()` from `onPostExecute()`, as you are already on the UI thread. Passing a `Thread` to `runOnUiThread()` is very strange. Beyond that, use Traceview to figure out where your time is being taken up (my guess is with whatever `ImageLoader` is) and do that work in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks Mark for informing me about `runOnUiThread()`, I also have same runnable like the above one and run it in `onResume()`, Does it have the same effect?

Comment: `onResume()` is called on the main application thread, and therefore `runOnUiThread()` is not necessary there either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off-  onPostExexute already runs in the UI thread.  No need for it to call RunOnUIThread, that will just slow it down.

My other big suggestion would be to precalculate a lot of this stuff in doInBackground, rather than doing it in onPostExecute.  But that won't decrease the total time to display, just where its taking the time.  If you need more speedup than that, run it in a profiler with the debugger turned off and see whats taking the most time.